# hibernate flush without commit, using manual flushmode

Tags: hibernate, commit, flush

I've been googling a lot about flush(), commit() and I have read the hibernate bible ( Java Persistance with Hibernate).

There still seems to be some inconsistency in my understanding of how these methods work.

Here is a somewhat puzzling observation:

Let us assume that we use manual flushmode.
We start a new session,start a transaction, load and modify some persistent objects and then flush and close the session BUT we do not execute the commit method on the transaction during this process.

As far as I understand ( from the hibernate bible), in this case the modifications are *not* saved to the database even though flush() was called. Is this a correct observation?

Here is an other, related question, the [hibernate javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush()) says:

> Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory.

What does this mean exactly ? The term synchronization is a little vague here, this description does not explain ( what more, contradicts! ) the above mentioned observation.

Could someone please precisely clarify the meaning of the word synchronization here as I cannot find the answer to this question neither on the net nor in the hibernate bible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below should help:

As far as I understand ( from the hibernate bible), in this case the modifications are not saved to the database even though flush() was called. Is this a correct observation? 
: **yes it is correct.**

> Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory.

**it means that the state of the entities are syncronized with the state of the database.**

Could someone please precisely clarify the meaning of the word synchronization here as I cannot find the answer to this question neither on the net nor in the hibernate bible:

Consider that you change the state of an object(by changing any attribute of that object) while that object is associated with session. Now the state object the object is not same as that of the database(row in your database table). Here, the moment you call flush, an update query is generated by hibernate, to update the database with this state.

But is the update operation committed?no, you need to issue an commit to make sure that this update is actually reflected in DB.

So the synchronization part that is confusing you is nothing but making sure that database and your entities are in sync.

Actually, when you call commit(), it implicitly calls flush() by default.

Answer (score 0):

yes, when we call flush() method on session, the changes of the object syncs with 
DB related Entity, But it will not update to the DB. when we call Commit() then it will be update.